# Get source code instead iframe

Tags: html, iframe

How I can get source code of iframe but to show all web site code who is in iframe when I click in my browser (right click/source code)...
Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/XWgnU/

UPDATE: What I'm need is to put URL in text field enter Submit and show the page with they source code below. Is it possible?

Comment: ... or get with curl or something else... ???

Answer (score 0):

[You can't run JavaScript on a third party page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) loaded in my browser, with my cookies, my ip address and anything else that site might use to authenticate me.

Comment: is there any way to generate a page when I get content with curl?

Comment: What I'm need is to put URL in text field enter Submit and show the page with they source code below. Is it possible?